# Написание тестов для функций с пользовательским вводом

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать тесты для функции, в составе которой есть пользовательский ввод при помощи window.prompt(), передаваемых аргументов в функцию нет. Вопрос - как имитировать пользовательский ввод в тестах?

Comment: сделать мок `window.prompt` - который будет возвращать то что нужно